# How to run the rmiregistry and rmi server with the right parameters?

Tags: java, rmi

How to run the rmiregistry and RMI server with the right parameters on the remote host?

Got this problem when running the RMI client:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at com.labros.client.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:33)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I started the rmiregistry on the remote host with the following:

```
rmiregistry -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///export/home/timsadm/Projects/rmi-server/cla‌​sses -J-Djava.security.policy=/export/home/timsadm/Projects/rmi-server/classes/java.p‌​olicy &
```

and the server with

```
java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///export/home/timsadm/Projects/rmi-server/class‌​es -Djava.security.policy=/export/home/timsadm/Projects/rmi-server/classes/java.pol‌​icy com.labros.server.Server

Server started
```

Comment: started the rmiregistry on the remote host with the following:

john@john:~/Projects/rmi-server/classes$ rmiregistry -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///export/home/timsadm/Projects/rmi-server/classes -J-Djava.security.policy=/export/home/timsadm/Projects/rmi-server/classes/java.policy &

and the server with: 

john@john:~/Projects/rmi-server/classes$ java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///export/home/timsadm/Projects/rmi-server/classes -Djava.security.policy=/export/home/timsadm/Projects/rmi-server/classes/java.policy com.labros.server.Server
Server started ...

Comment: You should [edit] that into your question, not post it as comments.

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted, and do use code formatting for text that is code, or computer output.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///export/home/timsadm/Projects/rmi-server/class‌​es
```

and

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
```

These are mutually contradictory. I suspect your codebase parameter really looks like this:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=c:/export/home/timsadm/Projects/rmi-server/class‌​es
```

which isn't a valid URL.

But why are you using the codebase feature at all? A `file:` codebase URL only works within a single host, in which case you don't need the codebase feature at all, or if it specifies a shared filesystem from the point of view of the Registry and the client, which this one doesn't appear to do. Normally codebase URLs are `http:` or `ftp:`, and they refer to a JAR file.